# Get all keys currently pressed down in c

Tags: c, macos, unix

I am making a command-line program where I need the cursor's position to change when you use the arrow keys. Previously I turned off canonical mode with `raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON);`, and git input with `read()` (defined in `unistd.h`). This made it function in a similar way to the `getch` function defined in `conio.h` on Windows. However, this returns the last character pressed. So if I want to move the cursor from the bottom-right to the top-left, I can't hold down `< + ^` to do that. How could I do this. If it is relevant, I am using the Alacritty terminal on MacOS 11. And lastly, It would be nice if the solution worked on other unix-like systems such as Linux and FreeBSD.

Comment: Have you looked at ncurses?

Comment: If I understand well, you want to detect when several keys are pressed at the same time, and know which keys. Is it what you are asking?